# How to change size image in archive category woocommerce

Tags: image, categories, woocommerce

I'm testing shop with plugin WooCommerce. I want to ask how to change size thumbnail image in archive category.
 ex: http://shop.bits77.com/?product_cat=giay-dep
I can change size in index.php  ex: http://shop.bits77.com 
But I dont know how to change in archive category.
Please help me. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

By default, Woocommerce have this thumbnails sizes:

- 300x300 (Single product) /* 300px is my size, im not remember exactly what is default size but, is similar */
- 120x120 (Gallery - Categories - Archive Page - Search products)
- 90x90 (Thumbnails in single product)

Now, you can change it in Woocommerce admin panel (Configure -> Catalog -> Scroll to bottom page -> Images).

Excuse my english and good luck.

Comment: Hi Roman,I've size theme. but it not working. still default size. do you know file .php archive product?

Comment: Thank you MrRoman, didn't know my catalog images were being requested bigger than it should. I fixed it now, hope it improves my page load time.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had to get the plugin called  ["Regenerate Thumbnails"](http://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/). Run that plugin and it will re-size the thumbnails for you.

Comment: Obviously an old question/answer, but note that this doesn't re-size anything. It only regenerates new thumbnails (clue is in the name) based on the sizes you define in functions.php.